# jqPlot, char names for Y-axis Ticks

Tags: jquery, char, jqplot

This is my first asked-myself question on stackoverflow - a site that has helped me so many times already. Please be understanding :)

I have problems with jqPlot that looks really simple, but its seems not to be.

I want to give static char names in Y axis (ticks). Y-axis values comes from real height on the Y-axis. I would like to create names like: value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4, value 5... instead of (for example) 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 7.0, 100.0...

Is it possible with jqPlot configuration alone. I could not see option as such, but maybe there is one, and I will feel ashamed :).

Thank you in advance for any help.

(EDIT) Here is the FULL code I used:

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line_oczekiwana_srednia, line_sd_plus_1, line_sd_plus_2, line_sd_plus_3, line_sd_plus_4, line_sd_minus_1, line_sd_minus_2, line_sd_minus_3, line_sd_minus_4, line1, line_WEST4, ], {
    animate: true,
    title:'OLYMPUS LEVEL 1 0029 : Kontrola biochemii. Typ materiału: Surowica', 
    axes:{
      xaxis:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{ 
          formatString:'%#d-%m-%y %#H:%M',
          angle: -30,
        },
        tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        label:'Zakres czasu kontroli', 
        labelOptions:{
          fontFamily:'Helvetica',
          fontSize: '14pt'
        },
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
      },           
      yaxis:{
        numberTicks: 9,
        ticks:[3.6284,3.6863,3.7442,3.8021,3.8600,3.9179,3.9758,4.0337,4.0916],
        renderer:$.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{
          showGridline: false,
          **formatString:'SDx:%.1f',**
          labelPosition: 'middle', 
          angle:-0,
        },
        tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        labelOptions:{
            fontFamily:'Helvetica',
            fontSize: '14pt'
        },
        label:'Wartości (mmol/l)'
      },        
    },
    highlighter: {
      show: true,
      sizeAdjust: 12.5,
    },
    cursor: {
      show: true,
      zoom:true,
      dblClickReset:true,
      tooltipLocation:'sw'
    },        
    series:[
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#76a4e8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},                                                            
      {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
      {lineWidth:2, color: '#f4ad31', rendererOptions: {animation: {speed: 1500}}, markerOptions:{color: 'gray', style:'filledSquare'}},
      {showLine: false, color: 'red', markerOptions:{color: 'red', style:'filledSquare'}},
    ],
    legend:{
       renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
       show: true,
       hideZeros: true,
       location: 'se',
       labels: ['Oczekiwana średnia (3.8600)', 'SD+1 (3.9179)', 'SD+2 (3.9758)', 'SD+3 (4.0337)', 'SD+4 (4.0916)', 'SD-1 (3.8021)', 'SD-2 (3.7442)', 'SD-3 (3.6863)', 'SD-4 (3.6284)', 'Wyniki kontroli (3.6284)', 'Reguła WEST4', ]
    }        

});
```

Comment: Can you please put the code which you have used, and if possible, show us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: So you want a line chart with y values as decimal but the actual tick labels to be replaced with labels?

Comment: Yes I have 9 values in total: -SD4, -SD3, -SD2, -SD1, MEAN, SD1, SD2, SD3, SD4. All those SD values are calculated in program, but on the y-axis I just want those corresponding names (for UI purouses)

Comment: Another question I would have is: How to add a second Y-axis to this code. I tried to use y2axis: { ........... } but I could not make it work, but unlike the problem i topic I saw working examples. I suspect its a matter of renderer, but I already use other renderer for sth else. Do I have to choose? I guess I should add new topics for this?

Comment: Concerning the fiddle: I run the test and it said "Your JS code is valid.". Is this what you meant Praveen? I never used that tool before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the ticks as [`[val, label]`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.ticks) pairs.  Note that they must be ordered properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,1,4,6]],{
           axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: [[1,'-SD1'],[3,'-SD4'],[4,'MEAN'],[6,'SD1'],[7,'-SD3']]
                }
           }});
});​
```

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x2gtL/1/).

Comment: In my case I just added ticks: [[0, ''], ... to have the labels start on line 1, instead of at the bottom 0